# Azure DevOps tabs hanging on edit

Tags: azure-devops

We host Azure DevOps in-house, Version Dev18.M170.6. The userbase is around 30 active users.

Multiple users are reporting the below behaviour:

- User has 2 or 3 (often more) tabs open
- User edits a task or bug on tab 1, and clicks Save
- Tab shows a spinning wheel, which persists until tab 2 (or often more) is closed

There are no messages on-screen, and no warnings in the server logs.

What could be causing this, and how do we prevent it from persisting?

Answer (score 1):

This should be a [known issue](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/waiting-for-available-socket/1247090) on the Developer Community site. You can refer to it for details.

As workaround, you can try:

- upgrad to [Azure DevOps Server 2020.1 RC1 Release Date: March 23,
  2021](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/server/release-notes/azuredevops2020u1?view=azure-devops#azure-devops-server-20201-rc1-release-date-march-23-2021)
- Use Firefox browser